# Load new elements and take them with Selenium and HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a site which has title and comments. When the page is loaded 40 comments are rendered, but after clicking the button "Load comments" there are new 40 comments and so on. I want to load all the comments first, and then take them all.
The problem is that I'm getting only the first 40. This is my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();    
driver.get(www.website.com);
String title = driver.findElement(By.className("title")).getText();

while(driver.findElements(By.className("load-comments")).isDisplayed() || !driver.findElement(By.className("expand-loading")).isDisplayed()){
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    if(!driver.findElements(By.className("loading")).isDisplayed()){
                        driver.findElements(By.className("load-comments")).click();
                    }
                }


List<WebElement> comments = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.className("comment"));
for(WebElement comm:comments){
   System.out.print(comm.getText());
}
```

So, if i need all 150 comments, in this situation i'm getting only the first 40 that are visible when the page is loaded.

I tried `options.addArguments("--headless");` with `ChromeDriver(options);` but it's very slow.

PS: The *load-comments* button is hidden when all comments are loaded and the *loading* element is displayed if the page is loading new comments.

Answer (score 0):

The website you provided din't display any comments. please provide exact web address to locate elements.
Why are you using "driver.findelements" instead of "driver.findelement" for is displayed condition? This logic will give you compilation error.
You need to add argument to set screen resolution while using headless.I suggest you to go with chrome with ui first then check the headless.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en

I need to take all comments for few applications from google play store. So I need to load all comments first, and then collect them all. The problem is that i need the crawler to be headless. When i'm trying this with ChromeDriver everything works perfect, but with HtmlUnitDriver the crawler collects only the first 40 comments.

Comment: In the given web,I am unable to find any class with "load-comments".

Comment: Can you try phantomJS and take screen shot on load...If the screen is not maximized then it may take as element not displayed.Try maximizing browser by adding arguments

Comment: The code is just an example, it is not the real code because it is more complex.